# Create array of floats from csv Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, csv

I have once again a beginner problem. I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
3.4,2.4,6.30,2.2,53.42,54,1,5
```

Now, I have a code that can parse this into an array

```
NSError *error;
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"csv_file" ofType:@"csv" inDirectory:nil];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *array = [array componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

The issue I have is that I can't do math with these numbers (because they are char - or maybe string, not sure -).

My question is, Is there a way like I did but to create the array with floats, or is there a way to make the strings (or chars) in `array` into floats.

Thank you, and of course if my question isn't clear just let me know.

Comment: FYI, the array contains `NSString` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the elements in the array remain instances of `NSString` (this is what they are). Just when you access an element from the array make it a float like this:

```
float f = [array[index] floatValue];
```

You can't have `NSArray` of floats in Objective-C because `NSArray` may contain objects only.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the `floatValue` property

```
float sum = 0;
for (NSString *numberString in array) {
    sum += [numberString floatValue];
}
```

If you want to put them in a C array:

```
float floatArray[array.count];
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(floatArray); i++)  { 
    NSString *numberString = array[i];
    floatArray[i] = [numberString floatValue];
}
```

Note that this way of creating a c array will add it to the stack; you'll need to use `malloc` if you want to add it to the heap.